# REQUEST: Japanese fountain / Shishi-odoshi

Tags: ambience, water, sound-effects-recording

Does anyone happen to have a recording of Japanese bamboo fountain they might be willing to share/trade?  Unfortunately I'm not in a position to recording one at the moment, although I have wanted to record these for a while in their natural, outdoor environment.

I'm speaking of this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shishi-odoshi

I would prefer something where you can both hear the hit and water trickles/pours (it's going to play mostly offstage so if it's just the 'hit' by itself it won't read all too well - I can automate the hit transients down a touch to balance if needed).  Only one recording long enough to loop (and not sound loopy) should be fine.

Overall not a big deal, I can live without it, but if someone might be willing to do a share/trade I would be grateful.  As always, willing to do a trade.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one, recorded in Nikko Japan - happy to trade for something equally idiosyncratic :)
email me so i don't forget tim@soundbite.co.nz

You will have automate levels/layer water trickle with it - the 'klunk' is so much louder than anything else....

http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/japan-field-trip-shishi-odoshi

Comment: Thanks Tim, will be in touch in the AM!  Very generous of you to offer.  The sample sounds great.